# Excel updating automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, automatic-update, embedding

I have two excel worksheets, one for Project Officers and one for Project Managers.

So we don't create more work for the project officers I would like to make it so when the POs update their spread sheet it automatically updates the PMs one as well. Is this possible??

I have read some things which suggests I can do this with Word and Excel using 'embedding' but both the spread sheets need to be Excel.

Comment: A few questions: When you say worksheets, do you mean sheets or workbooks? As in, are both accessing the same book, but looking at different sheets? If you're looking at updating seperate books are they stored in the same place? And finally; the data that the PMs see is the data the POs entered, but in a different sheet/book?